# Error passing serializable custom object between two activities android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

in my program I must to pass a custom object between two activities. The second activity start after click on an item of a listview in the first activity. The code in OnItemClick of first activity is:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                Intent userProfileIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        UserProfileActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("contact", new ContactSerializer(
                        sortContacts.get(position)));
                userProfileIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                v.getContext().startActivity(userProfileIntent);

            }
```

The code of second activity is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.userprofile_layout);

    ContactSerializer serializer = (ContactSerializer) getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra("contact");

    CustomObj contact = serializer.getContact();
```

And the code of the serializable object is:

```
public class ContactSerializer implements Serializable {

private CustomObj contact;

public ContactSerializer(CustomObj contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public CustomObj getContact() {
    return contact;
}
```

}

My LogCat is:

```
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.app.ContactSerializer)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6660)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1865)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1412)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at com.app.MyProfileActivity$ContactsLoader$1.onItemClick(MyProfileActivity.java:153)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
070 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.CustomObj
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
07-10 13:07:57.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1333):     ... 25 more
```

The application crash when I try to start the second activity (on line v.getContext.startActivity....). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you print your logcat please

Comment: Have you made sure that CustomObj is also serializable? Because if it is not, serialization will simply fail.

Comment: Uhm actually I seeing the logcat I noticed that my method is not serializable. How can I do to pass between activities?

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.CustomObj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CustomObj should also implement serializable:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.CustomObj

If the CustomObj again contains other objects, make sure that those also implement serializable. You don't have to look out for simple types like String or Double because those implement serializable.

Comment: How can I do to pass the object between two activities?

Comment: Your code already passes it if I am correct by using a Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Create a serializable object using java.io.Serializable

```
private Class CustomObject implements Serializable
{
   ...
}
```

Intents already send serializable data using the put extra method. This first activities transition with a serializable payload looks like this:

```
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();  

Intent i = new Intent(ThisClass.this, ThatOtherActivity.class);
i.putExtra("foobar", obj);  
startActivity(i);
```

The receiving activity would look something like this.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) i.getSerializableObject("foobar");
```

Now remember. If CustomObject houses other custom objects. Make sure those custom objects implement Serializable as well.